# Titlesec creates entry in ToC for a starred part

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, titlesec, parts, starred-version

I have the following code, creating section titles starting with "Section [number].", exactly as I wish:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newcommand\sectiontext{}
\titleformat{\section}%
    {\refstepcounter{section}%
    \renewcommand\sectiontext{Section \thesection. #1}%
    \Large\bfseries}
    {}
    {0pt}
    {\sectiontext}
    [\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\sectiontext}]
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section*{A section}
\section*{Another section}
\end{document}
```

(The macro `sectiontext` is used for clarity.) Also in the table of contents the sections are displayed as I want (except for the Contents itself, but I know how to fix that), and `hyperref` creates exactly the right links:

```
% Contents entry for the contents itself left out
\contentsline {section}{Section 2. A section}{1}{section.2}
\contentsline {section}{Section 3. Another section}{1}{section.3}
```

(Don't mind the Contents entry, it is numbered as the first section.) Note that starred sections must be used. Summarizing, there is no problem here.

A problem arises when I use a completely analogous code for parts instead of sections:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newcommand\parttext{}
\titleformat{\part}%
    {\refstepcounter{part}%
    \renewcommand\parttext{Part \thepart. #1}%
    \Huge\bfseries}
    {}
    {0pt}
    {\parttext}
    [\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\parttext}]
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part*{A part}
\part*{Another part}
\end{document}
```

Using this, the ToC file becomes:

```
% Contents entry for the contents itself left out
\contentsline {part}{Part I. A part}{1}{part.1}
\contentsline {part}{A part}{1}{part.1}
\contentsline {part}{Part II. Another part}{1}{part.2}
\contentsline {part}{Another part}{1}{part.2}
```

As you can see, `titlesec` creates an additional entry for each part. (This is also the case when I don't load `hyperref`.)
This is really strange, because it is almost the same code as for sections. How can I remove those entries?

Comment: `\part` is understood, and defined, to be at a "higher" level than `\section`, so it will automatically be included in the toc for any `\tocdepth` greater than 1.  what you should consider instead is using `\subsection` instead of `\part`, but changing the text of the heading to read "Part" if you want that, or omit that name if you don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason here is that [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) just handles `\part`s differently to all other sectional units within a document. It sets up a separate handler to manage the titles and ToC-related entries, *always* writing the latter for `\part`. As such, your "after code" which adds the ToC-related entry for `\part` is followed by `titlesec` writing it as well, hence the dual entries in your ToC.

How do you obtain the output you're after? Patch `\ttl@part@i` (with the aid of [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)) to insert your `\parttext` as part of its natural ToC-writing and drop the manual writing:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ttl@part@i}% <cmd>
  {{#1}{#3}}% <search>
  {{#1}{Part \thepart. #3}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\newcommand\parttext{}    
\titleformat{\part}%
  {\refstepcounter{part}\Huge\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\parttext}
  []

\newcommand\sectiontext{}
\titleformat{\section}%
  {\refstepcounter{section}%
  \renewcommand\sectiontext{Section \thesection. #1}%
  \Large\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\sectiontext}
  [\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\sectiontext}]

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part*{A part}
\part*{Another part}

\section*{A section}
\section*{Another section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. There is one more issue. I wish the very last part not to be numbered, i.e. have a title 'Title' and not 'Part IV: Title'. I tried to use `{{#1}{\iftoggle{partnum}{Part \thepart. }{}#3}}` instead of `{{#1}{Part \thepart. #3}}` (`partnum` is toggled false right before that last part), but this doesn't work, at least not for the ToC. Perhaps I should put a `\edef` or `\expandafter` or something before `\iftoggle`?

Comment: Never mind, I used `\patchcmd` again right before that part. It's an ugly solution but I only have to do it once, so I can live with that.